# How to pass cookie from Java Web Start to browser?

Tags: java, cookies, browser

When using Java Web Start to open a URL in the browser with showDocument(), there is a problem passing the cookie to browser. But we need the cookie in the request header to indicate the session has been authenticated. 
But I could't find out a way to pass the cookie from Java Web Start to the browser.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This js code may help you, but you should instance a cookie in java code

```
 function getCookie(cookieName) {//get cookie with cookieName
             var arrStr = document.cookie.split("; ");
             for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
                 var temp = arrStr[i].split("=");
                 if (temp[0] == cookieName)
                     return unescape(temp[1]);
             }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks bran. This codes could get cookie in a browser. But it seems that I still couldn't set the cookie from java web start for the browser...